# Getting an import error in kivy python kivy.properties

Tags: python, kivy

i need help with kivy here
whenever i use `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty` it gives error
can any one help me and i use the import as krypos method didn't workout.

additional info im using pycharm and 3.7 python of course

https://gyazo.com/e30fac30a46ae4d8abe68be3258adfcf

here is the image it gives error...

keep in mind all other imports are working just fine

Comment: Does the program run correctly? If it does, this is just a mistake from your IDE's linter.

Comment: yeah it was also just a python version error i didn't see evreything worked